# Imprimir arreglo en JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

Necesito que un arreglo que meto en un JSON y lo guardo en localStorage pueda agregar un valor a un arreglo que ya este guardado

Aqui es donde guardo el arreglo:

```
var palabra = $("#txtpalabra").val();

        var pista =  $("#txtpista").val();

        Palabras.push(palabra);
        Pistas.push(pista);
        localStorage.setItem("Palabras", JSON.stringify(Palabras));
        localStorage.setItem("Pistas", JSON.stringify(Pistas));
```

Y lo guarda asi:

```
0:"santos" 1:"laguna"
```

Y necesito que lo guarde asi:

```
0:{"santos", "laguna"}
```

Comment: Las variables `Palabras` y `Pistas` cómo están en un principio? O directamente las creas ahí?

Comment: Las obtengo del localStorage:

`var Palabras = localStorage.getItem("Palabras");
     Palabras = JSON.parse(Palabras);`

Comment: Guardarlo de la segunda manera no va a ser posible, las llaves `{}` representan a un objeto en javascript. La única manera es como un array y es la forma en que lo guarda. Por qué necesitás ese tipo de formato?

Comment: Lo uso en un js que arma el juego del ahorcado, de momento tengo un arreglo fijo para poder escoger la palabra:

`play = function () {
  categories = [
   ["everton", "liverpool", "swansea"]
  ];

  chosenCategory = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
  word = chosenCategory[Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenCategory.length)];
  word = word.replace(/\s/g, "-");
  console.log(word);
  buttons();

  geusses = [ ]
  lives = 10;
  counter = 0;
  space = 0;
  result();
  comments();
  //selectCat();
  canvas();
 }`

Comment: Y en dónde lo requerís esa variable con el formato del que estás hablando? Probablemente estés llamandolo mal.

Answer (score 0):

JSON tiene la estructura de {llave: valor, llave: valor}
Talvez lo que quieres es esto:

```
{
    palabras: ["palabra1", "palabra2"],
    pistas: ["pista1", "pista2"]
}
```

Comment: Necesito que sean arreglos separados, no en un mismo JSON

Answer (score 0):

Debes parsear lo que obtienes del LocalStorage ya que obtienes una cadena y necesitas que vuelva a ser un array, aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como guardar dos arrays en el LocalStorage y obtenerlos de nuevo:

```
var Palabras = ['hola', 'javascript']
var Pistas = ['j', 's']

// Guardas en LocalStorage los valores en forma de cadena usando JSON.stringify

localStorage.setItem('Palabras', JSON.stringify(Palabras))
localStorage.setItem('Pistas', JSON.stringify(Pistas))

// Obtienes los valores y los parseas con JSON.parse

Palabras = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Palabras'))
Pistas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Pistas'))

// Estos son arrays
console.log(Palabras[1]) // 'javascript'
console.log(Pistas[0]) // 'j'
```